# Can I generate a 3d map using 2d lidar data?

Tags: ros, laser, octomap-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know how to approach this problem. I was thinking of using octomap but since there are no tutorials available I can't seem to pick a starting point. Are there any other packages that I can use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209617/can-i-generate-a-3d-map-using-2d-lidar-data?/) by [hgtc-dp](https://answers.ros.org/users/15556/hgtc-dp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-05-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the name suggests, OctoSLAM performs mapping and localization though. In case you are only interested in mapping your laser scans given that you know the 6D pose of the sensor it's quite straight forward:

1. Convert laser scan to pcd (http://wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry)
2. Provide tf between sensor and world frame (http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials)
3. Map the laser scans using http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server

---

Originally posted by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) with karma: 365 on 2015-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-01-19**:
Hi jodafo, i converted laser scan to pcd but was not able to provide tf between laser and world frame. Is it possible to generate 3d map without imu? If yes, then what should i do to generate 3d map?
thanks in advance.

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-03-31**:
You need an external SLAM or localization node to provide the map-->odom or map-->base_link transform